# LDAP gitlab not working

Tags: ldap, centos7, gitlab

I have been at least two days trying to make this work with Active directory.

when I run this command  see the result:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check RAILS_ENV=production                                               Checking LDAP ...

Server: ldapmain
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

However I can´t log in using AD users, it says invalid credentials.
This is my config file (/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb)

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS
 main:
     label: 'Active Directory'
     host: 'dc.example.com'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     encryption: 'plain'
     bind_dn: 'userldap@example.com'
     password: 'userldap_password'
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'ou=Users,DC=example,DC=com
EOS'
```

This running on CentOS 7.
Please some help.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Comment: There are some [good suggestions here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html#invalid-credentials-when-logging-in). Have you tried all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that it's `ActiveDirectory` instead of `Active Directory`.

Second you can define a timeout e.g.: `timeout: 10`

Probably because your ldap is succeeding you might want to check your user_filter or your base DN.

Furthermore the config file is space-sensitive:

- One space before main
- 2 spaces before each line below main
- no space before EOS

Also after you made changes make sure to do a **gitlab-ctl reconfigure**.

Comment: it was mainly a mistake with the ou. thanks for your answer.